# Application that works on webrick but fails in passenger

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a ruby on rails application that starts successfully when I execute `rails s -p 3000`.

But when I deploy it on apache or nginx using passenger, I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF4O5.png).

The deployment instructions are the common ones for each platform, using the passenger module. Also the port is free.

I looked in the [startup problems wiki](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems) but I do not know how to check the stdout redirection issue (which is the startup script). Is there any wiki that explains this steps with examples?

The configuration for nginx is the following

```
...
http {
 passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.40;
 passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby;
 passenger_log_level 1;
 passenger_start_timeout 15;
 passenger_load_shell_envvars off;
 ...
 server {
   listen 3000;
   #server_name x.x.x.x;
   server_name localhost;
   root /home/rails_apps/moi/public/;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env development;
   charset utf-8;
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean to have this in development instead of production?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it does not have to be in development. But in production the result is the same.

Comment: Please note what you did in response to the _other_ possible causes noted in the wiki.